# How to make a reverse in DefaultRouter()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm setting up a new tests, and i want to make an reverse.

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('profile', views.UserProfileViewSet, base_name='profile')

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'', include(router.urls))
]
```

UserProfileViewSet

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   """Handles creating, creating and updating profiles."""

   serializer_class = serializers.UserProfileSerializer
   permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateOwnProfile,)
   authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

   queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
```

So , i want make a reverse in tests.py. my shot is:

```
CREAT_USER_URL = reverse('profile-create')
```

And I simply get:

> Reverse for 'profile-create' not found. 'profile-create' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

How should I set up a reverse in this case.

Comment: can you add `UserProfileViewSet` view?/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use **`profile-list`** instead of `profile-create`

`CREAT_USER_URL = reverse('profile-list')`

There is no URL as `{base_name}-create`, If you wanna use create endpoint, use `{base_name}-list`.

For more information, [refer to this table](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter)

Comment: Thank you i have used app_name in urls.py that's why first time profile-list didn't work for me