# How to reverse a url that is using DefaultRouter()?

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to use reverse() inside my test. I tried  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048356/how-to-make-a-reverse-in-defaultrouter)! but it's not working.
I still getting the error
 `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'patients-list' with no arguments not found`.

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'patients', views.PatientSet, base_name='patients')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Here is the `ModelViewSet`

```
class PatientSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PatientSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsDoctorUser]
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ['is_active']
```

I'm using this way inside my test `url = reverse('patients-list')`

Comment: Can you provide your `PatientSet`? It looks like it was found, but requires argument for `-list` url name.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: seems like you forgot to add the URLs config to ***`urlpatterns`*** list. It should be `urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]` @Zoro-Zen

Comment: My bad for not add it properly in the question, but I have it in my urlpatterns list. Updated the question again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Firstly, the `base_name` kwarg to routers is deprecated in favor of the `basename` kwarg in DRF 3.11, however this should not be what's causing issues.  I can't actually see anything wrong with the code sample you've provided either.

What I would recommend is try installing the [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_instructions.html) package.  After you have installed and configured django-extensions, you can use the `python manage.py show_urls` command to output a list of all your routes.

> python manage.py show_urls

```
/api/accounts/users/ accounts.views.UserViewSet account:user-list
/api/accounts/users/<uuid>/ accounts.views.UserViewSet account:user-detail
```

Each line contains the url `/api/accounts/users/<uuid>/`, the view's path `accounts.views.UserViewSet`, and the *name* (this is what you want for reverse) of the route `account:user-detail`.  With this I hope you will be able to find the correct name for your route.  The URL portion also indicates any parameters required for that route.

Comment: It worked. I used the comand `python manage.py show_urls`, and the correct url to reverse is `admin:patient_add`.

Comment: I am searching to reverse() the raw urls instead  of the example done by RonanFelipe but a raw url instead to pass some params.

Comment: @EliasPrado Your question should probably be a seperate topic, but you are looking to use the `django.utils.resolver()` method